# save output and execution time of command in diffrent variables in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to save the output of the find command in $path variable, and save the execution time of this command in t variable.

something like this, but its incorrect.

```
t=`time path=`find . -type d  -iname "$x"` `
```

the blow command works well, but this is in the loop and I want to have the sum of the time in a variable

```
time path=`find . -type d  -iname "$x"`
```

Comment: Don't use backticks, use `$()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary file and GNU time:

```
TMPFILE="$(mktemp)"
path="$( /usr/bin/time -o "$TMPFILE" find . -type d  -iname "$x" )"
t="$(cat "$TMPFILE")"
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

For higher security, you can also use a temporary directory etc.